# How to hide image link, i.e mask the repository from where it is fetched

Tags: javascript, html

I need to develop functionality in which there are multiple images fetched from different resources. Users(Clients) should not see repository details from which images are fetched.

If not possible, is there a way to create a directory at the client (browser cache) and put those images there and delete them after user logouts.

Comment: Create APIs to send images.

Comment: i need to show them on browser window.

Comment: Use that api url in place of direct mage url.

Comment: will browser display that image?? If i have a rest url "/getImage/imageId" and keep it in src will be displayed on UI??

Comment: If you hit your direct image url, It sends data in binary only. With API you can send data in base 64 and directly use that or you can set a content type with raw data.

Comment: base64 eats up ot of memory.. we get performance issues.. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to have a backend generating data: URLs on the server instead of referencing images by URL. Any URL you send to the client can be discovered through developer tools or network sniffers.

Comment: "0URLs on the server instead of referencing images by URL" - can you brief me on this? we have tomee as server.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what server you are using at background.

I've created a example using node sever.

**My Server:**

```
const express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , http = require('http').createServer(app);


app.use(express.static('./views'));

app.get('/image1', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('public/test.png', { root: __dirname });
});

http.listen('8080', () => {
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <img src='./image1' />
    </body>
</html>
```